# Formula field to select either of the two date option to return a number

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to create a formula field that we chooose Formula should show time between cancel requested and either cancel confirmed date, saved date or deferred date - whichever one is populated.

The formula that i have made is :

```
IF (
     Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Saved_Date__c, 
     Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c
)
```

But I am not sure that is the right way of doing this, suggestions needed

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
 IF (
         Saved_Date__c!=NULL,
         Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Saved_Date__c, 
         IF(Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c!=NULL,
            Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c,
            IF(Deferred_date__c!=NULL,
               Cancellation_Requested_Date__c -Deferred_date__c ,
               NULL
            )
         )
       )
```

Dont forget to accept answer if its helpful. Tia

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply but its not populating the field ? Can you think of any reason that why its happening

Comment: is your Cancellation_Requested_Date__c populated ? it will populate only if Cancellation_Requested_Date__c is populated & either of Saved_Date__c,Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c or Deferred_date__c is populated

Comment: Yes i have populated the dates

Comment: It will be great if you more clarify your requirement with example, Since @snehakem answers looks good. OR What is Return type of your Formula field ? Is it throwing any error, or values - if yes what is it ?

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: If your fields data type is DateTime then Formula field data type must also be DateTime. If your fields data type is Date then Formula field data type must also be Date.

Comment: Hey Sneha the formula field is a number field, Because i want to Calculate the no of days/Age it has taken from Cancellation Requested Date to Saved Date,Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c, Cancellation_Requested_Date__c -Deferred_date__c  Thanks a lot

Comment: Its not populating the formula field is blank

Comment: If(!IsBlank(Saved_Date__c),Abs(Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Saved_Date__c),If(!IsBlank(Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c),Abs( 
Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c),Abs(Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Date_Deferred_To__c)))  This is right way ! Thanks for the help Sneha

Answer (score 0):

IF (Saved_Date__c != null, Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Saved_Date__c, IF(Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c != null,Cancellation_Requested_Date__c - Cancellation_Confirmed_Date__c, null)
)

Comment: Shailendra -- best practice in answering questions on SFSE is to not just provide code but to a) format the code and b) explain why the code solves the problem - perhaps by identifying where the OP went astray.